# Map Java DTO in response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a Java map which I would like to map using DTO in response. I tried this:

Service:

```
@Service
public class GatewaysService {

    public Map<Integer, String> getGatewaysList() {    
        Map<Integer, String> list = new HashMap<>();    
        list.put(1, "Bogus");    
        return list;
    }
}
```

API:

```
@Autowired
private GatewaysService gatewaysService;

    @GetMapping("gateways")
        public ResponseEntity<?> getGateways() {
            return ok(gatewaysService.getGatewaysList().map(mapper::toGatewayMap));
        }
```

DTO:

```
public class ContractGatewaysDTO {

    private Integer id;

    private String gateway;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGateway() {
        return gateway;
    }

    public void setGateway(String gateway) {
        this.gateway = gateway;
    }
}
```

Mapper:

```
Map<Integer, String> toGatewayMap(ContractGatewaysDTO dto);
```

But I get error:

```
The method map(ContractDTO) in the type ContractsMapper is not applicable for the arguments (mapper::toGatewayMap)
```

What is the proper way to map it? I want to convert the Java map into key-value response.

Comment: Since when Map has `map` method?

Comment: *I want to convert the Java map into key-value response.* But map is exactly key-value. Just return it.

Comment: I agree but the other end - angular needs to know the keys.

Comment: And what does angular has to do with it. Client is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just

```
@Autowired
private GatewaysService gatewaysService;

    @GetMapping("gateways")
        public Map<String,String> getGateways() {
            return gatewaysService.getGatewaysList();
        }
```

You dont have to map anything here.

Moreover

Unless in Java 9+ something changed, I don't recall `java.uti.Map` to have `map` method like you use it here

```
gatewaysService.getGatewaysList().map(mapper::toGatewayMap)
```

What i *assume* you tried to do is something like this:

```
List<Dto> yourlist= gatewaysService.getGatewaysList() //why MAP is named a LIST idk;
                        .entrySet() //can be any streamable collection - this comes with maps;
                        .stream()
                        .map(entry->new Dto(entry.key(),entry.value())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If I remember correct if I do this I will get something like `{1, Bogus }`. I need to get content  `{id: 1, gateway: Bogus }`

Comment: I got map form this example: @GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> get(@PathVariable String id) {
        return contractRepository
                .findById(Integer.parseInt(id))
                .map(mapper::toDTO)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());

Comment: I can only assume what was expected output. Nevertheless I have added a proposition

Comment: Well having optional is very different than having list.

Comment: What do you mean by `//why MAP is named a LIST idk;`?

Answer (score 1):

What I was thinking is that you may want to convert the Map to the DTO entity, if it is what you need you can achieve by doing this:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(getGatewaysList()
                                    .entrySet()
                                    .stream()
                                    .map( g -> new ContractGatewaysDTO(g.getKey(), g.getValue()))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```